# Test of equality between arrays using in1d function

Tags: python, arrays, scipy

Before I ask my question, I provide you with the code:

```
from scipy import *
x = randn(10)
cum_x = cumsum(x)
# The objective is to recover x using cum_x and the diff function.
y = append(cum_x[0], diff(cum_x))
# Now, y should be equal to x but this is not confirmed by the function in1d
test = in1d(x,y)
```

The variable `test` does not return an array of "True" boolean values even if y and x are clearly the same. What is the problem here?

Comment: I imagine there are floating point issues, `allclose` might be what you want

Comment: It is. But why in1d does not return an array of True values? Why rounding issues? Do you think the cumulative sum and the difference produce slightly different floats?

Comment: I added an answer showing increased precision, you can see there are slight differences

Comment: Aside: even if `x` and `y` weren't clearly different, `in1d` isn't a good way to check to see if they're equal: -- `in1d([1,2],[2,1])` gives all true, after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use [set_printoptions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) to increase precision you will see some differences:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import *
np.set_printoptions(30)
x = randn(10)
cum_x = cumsum(x)

#The objective is to recover x using cum_x and the diff function.
y = append(cum_x[0], diff(cum_x))
print(x)
print("\n")
print(y)
#Now, y should be equal to x but this is not confirmed by the function in1d
test = in1d(x, y)
print(test)
```

Output:

```
[ 0.54816314147543721002620031868   0.14319052613251953554041051575
  0.489110961092741158839913850898 -0.093011827554544138085823590245
 -0.58370623188476589149331630324  -0.40395493550429123486011917521
  0.387387395892057895263604905267  1.001637373359834937147638811439
 -1.486778459872974744726548124163  1.446772274227251076084144187917]


[ 0.54816314147543721002620031868   0.143190526132519591051561747008
  0.48911096109274110332876261964  -0.093011827554544179719187013688
 -0.58370623188476589149331630324  -0.40395493550429123486011917521
  0.387387395892057895263604905267  1.001637373359834937147638811439
 -1.486778459872974744726548124163  1.446772274227251076084144187917]
[ True False False False  True  True  True  True  True  True]
```

What you probably want is [allclose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) but interestingly setting the dtype to `np.float128` or `np.longdouble` on my ubuntu system does not lose precision and in1d returns True.

```
 cum_x = cumsum(x,dtype=np.longdouble)
```

Comment: So do you think the cumulative sum and the difference functions produce these slight differences?

Comment: @Charlie, if you look  at the output they definitely do, what you want to be using is `allclose`.

Comment: `set_printoptions()` is in numpy package, not scipy